# $X_i \sim N(\theta,1), \theta \in \Bbb Z$: $T=\left\lfloor \bar X_n \right \rfloor$ not consistent for $\theta$

Tags: statistics, probability-theory

Let $\{X_i\}$ be a sample from a normal $N(\theta,1)$, where 
$\theta \in \Bbb Z$.
Show the estimator
$$
T=\left\lfloor \bar X _ n \right \rfloor,
$$
is not consistent for $\theta$, with $\bar X_n$ the sample mean of an $n$-sample.

Let $\epsilon >0$, I should show
$$
\lim_{n \to \infty}P\left( |T-\theta| > \epsilon \right)
=
\lim_{n \to \infty} P\left( \left|\left\lfloor \bar X _ n \right \rfloor - \theta \right| > \epsilon \right) \ne 0,
$$
but the integer part function confuses me.
I don't see the distribution of the random variable in the middle term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint:** If $\bar X_n<\theta$, then $\left\lfloor \bar X_n \right \rfloor\leq \theta-1$.
What is $P(\bar X_n<\theta)$?

Comment: \begin{align}
P\left( \left \lfloor \bar X_n \right \rfloor - \theta < -1/2 \right)
&= P\left( \left \lfloor \bar X_n \right \rfloor  < \theta -1/2 \right) 
P\left( \bar X_n < \theta \right) \\
&+P\left( \left \lfloor \bar X_n \right \rfloor  < \theta -1/2 \right)
P\left( \bar X_n \ge \theta \right) \\
&\ge 1 \cdot 1/2 + 0 \cdot 1/2 \\
&= 1/2.
\end{align}
Is it like that?

Comment: @NicolasEssis-Breton I don't follow your calculations at all. Using my hint, get some idea about $P\left(| \left \lfloor \bar X_n \right \rfloor - \theta| \geq 1\right)$.